# Where is clone Apps data stored in Realme 2 Pro (Color OS 5.2)?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, oppo-coloros, parallel-apps

Generally, WhatsApp data and media are found in the WhatsApp folder created in the file manager.

When we enable Clone Apps for WhatsApp in Realme 2 Pro (Color OS 5.2), where are cloned WhatsApp data and media stored and where can I find cloned WhatsApp data and media in file manager?

Comment: Cloned apps work under a different user account. `/sdcard` is actually `/data/media/0` where 0 is the UserID of default user accout i.e. the owner of the device. So the data of cloned WhatsApp must be at `/data/media/[UserID]/WhatsApp` but you can't access that path without root access. You should clone a file manager to access the files of cloned WhatsApp. Both apps would be working under same user account then.

Answer (score 2):

Open File Manager → Choose Phone Storage → defaults folders will be visible, select Search icon/text area and type `999` and click enter, you will be redirected to `999` folder with following pre-defined folders:

1. Android
2. DCIM
3. WhatsApp

Click on WhatsApp → Media, and find your relevant files like images, profile photos, videos, animated gifs, documents, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install FX File Explorer on playstore app
2. Go to Setting and allow hidden files
3. Go to internal storage
4. There is a small letter written "storage/emulated/0/", click on this and replace 999 to 0
5. Tap OK

Answer (score 0):

First, install any other file manager such as Xiaomi's file manager and then search 999, you will find the data and media of cloned WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

**Eureka!** Found a way and it can work wirelessly.
**Follow my tutorial, Just discovered it and currently backing up my WhatsApp folder.**

So, First → Get the [Filezilla client version.](https://filezilla-project.org/)

and [MiXplorer Silver - File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixplorer.silver&hl=en_IN&gl=US) . Paid Version. But you know what to do with the paid version , Won’t link the links. But go for it,

and obviously know the file path of the DUAL APPS folder in my case it’s `/storage/emulated/999/WhatsApp/……….`

**Now,** open Mixplorer and then to the right top corner click on the options and then click on Servers.

**Next,** click the edit button and set the path to the location of your Dual app `/storage/emulated/999`.

Now, **click start server**.

Next, Create Hotspot → Connect your Laptop/Desktop (using a dongle or inbuilt Wi-Fi) to the network then, Open Filezilla → You’ll need the location of your FTP server. As in our case, the server we created using MiXplorer,

**Note##** You’ll find the **FTP** address in the Notification menu of your phone by **MiXplorer**, Now in Filezilla Hostname will be the IP address mine was `192.168.XX.X`

and **port** (If you’ve created your port in MiXplorer) else leave it blank and Boom Now, you’re provided with the Storage screen and Just copy whatever you want from There.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And obviously, it’s efficient for any kind of file transfer using FTP i.e. Wirelessly.